# Account Contact role

Tags: contact

I'm working with a force.com org and I would like to write some application logic base on the contact role but in my Account page there is no such list available, I only see the regular contact list with no option to select contact role. 
Is there a place I need to enable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/contactroles.htm

You will find a related list under contact or person  for contact roles. The permissions needed to add contact roles are listed on above url